# What is this tube in the Space Shuttle Orbiter?

Tags: space-shuttle, identify-this-object

I found this picture of the left panel of the Orbiter:

[image]

What is the function of that small detachable tube?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That tube was slipped over the nosewheel steering (NWS) selector switch so that the commander could easily find it without taking their eyes out of the window in case of a nosewheel steering failure during rollout.

If the red circle in the picture in the question were a clock, the nosewheel steering selection switch is about at 6:30-7:00. You can see how it doesn't have the mushroom shaped top on it like the BODY FLAP or ENTRY MODE switches near it do.

This shot of page 7.4-20 in the [Shuttle Crew Operations Manual](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/390651main_shuttle_crew_operations_manual.pdf) will serve as a reference.

[image: screenshot of SCOM showing switch and extension device]

The extension was removed and stowed on the Velcro tab as shown in the picture in the question once the shuttle made it into orbit, and was reinstalled for entry.  These clips from the [Post Insertion](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/539932main_PI_134_F_2.pdf) and [Deorbit Prep](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/492871main_D-O_G_Q_5.pdf) checklists show those actions.

(Post Insertion)
[image: shot from PI checklist showing extension removal]

(Deorbit Prep)
[image: shot from DO Prep checklist showing extension mounting]

Comment: Surely that's more like 6:30-7:00?

Comment: @Cadence you are right. I was thinking that the tube in the question pointed at noon. Will fix. Thanks!

Comment: That's an interesting (and unusual) hack, I would have imagined a switch with a different color, with a slightly longer lever, not a transparent tube ;-)

Comment: @ocirocir I am trying to find a picture from the real orbiter or the simulator showing it in place. No luck so far.

Comment: @OrganicMarble found: in the first 360 view https://blog.kuula.co/virtual-tour-space-shuttle

Comment: @ocirocir that's awesome!

Comment: @ocirocir where did you find the picture in the question? It looks a lot like one I took.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Indeed ;-) https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24139/37103

Comment: @ocirocir Differently shaped handles was a common hack in aviation. You want something that not only looks different but *feels* quite different so under pressure you immediately know what you have your hand on. *Design Of Everyday Things* has an example of replacing critical levers in commercial airplane cockpits with beer tap handles.

Comment: @Schwern, I'm picturing the related instructions in the reference manual.  "Retract Budweiser to idle.  Set to Michelob to 10 degrees.  Extend Coors."

Comment: @Schwern It's been a few years since I read _The Design of Everyday Things_, but IIRC the tap handles were in the control room of a nuclear power plant, not an airplane cockpit.