# What is the most recent photo taken from the Moon surface as of August 2019?

Tags: camera

Everybody knows the Apollo imagery, but what are the recent Earth images taken from the Moon surface, if there are any? And which hardware was used to take the images and transmit them?

Comment: From the lunar surface, the photographer might be the Chang'e 3 lander or the Yutu rover. From *lunar orbit* it might be Chang'e 4 or some of its companions, cf. [What spacecraft components are in the foreground of this image of the Earth and Moon? What is the camera inside of?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33459/12102) But I don't know what the *most recent* photo might be, or if there is one from August 2019 or not. Also see http://planetary.org/blogs/guest-blogs/imaging-the-earth-from-lunar-orbit.html

Comment: and also https://gbtimes.com/a-tiny-chinese-satellite-is-orbiting-the-moon-and-allowing-radio-amateurs-download-images?feature=chinas-change-4-mission-to-the-far-side-of-the-moon and here's one possibly from August https://twitter.com/exploreplanets/status/1158506701051482112

Comment: Chang'e 4 just [took the first panorama of the far side of the moon](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/The_first_panorama_from_the_far_side_of_the_moon.jpg/1200px-The_first_panorama_from_the_far_side_of_the_moon.jpg). Also Chandrayaan-2 is en-route.