# Which camera has produced this image from Longjiang-2 microsatellite?

Tags: the-moon, earth, camera

Here is an [image](http://planetary.org/blogs/guest-blogs/2019/longjiang-2-impacts-moon.html) of this lunar micro-satellite taken in 2018, from [this tweet](https://twitter.com/exploreplanets/status/1158506701051482112), found in [this comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/38392/what-is-the-most-recent-photo-taken-from-the-moon-surface-as-of-august-2019#comment122648_38392) below the question [What is the most recent photo taken from the Moon surface as of August 2019?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38392/12102)

In the original source I've found: "captured by Longjiang-2/*DSLWP-B*"

[image]

Which camera exactly has taken this image and which hardware configuration was used to take and transmit the image? Is it even listed on the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chang%27e_4#Longjiang_microsatellites) page?

> - **Landing Camera (LCAM)**, mounted on the bottom of the spacecraft, the
>     camera began to produce a video stream at the height of 12 km (7.5 mi)
>     above the lunar surface.
> - **Terrain Camera (TCAM)**, mounted on top of the
>     lander and able to rotate 360°, is being used to image the lunar
>     surface and the rover in high definition.

Some more [data](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwjGhdOZ-KLkAhXSY1AKHcM-BaoQFjAAegQIABAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdestevez.net%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2018%2F09%2Fdslwp_en.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0RhE7TNOpP-DFkYZf_Fvk8) on the camera and also its [complete images archive](http://lilacsat.hit.edu.cn/dashboard/pages_en/pics-b.html):

> DSLWP-B carrier a camera designed by King Abdulaziz City for Science
>   and Technology [KACST] (Saudi Arabia)

Comment: @uhoh thanks for the reminder, did it.

Comment: @uhoh sorry for not referencing your comment; are SE comments a reliable source? i.e. you won't clean up as I've seen it sometimes.

Comment: A lead from another tweet:  https://twitter.com/aj_fi/status/1026432829322944513  "These images above are from a student-developed camera on the Longjiang-2/DSLWP-B microsatellite - a second imager distinct from the one developed by KACST of Saudi Arabia which took the images below. 2 cameras on one 47 kg lunar sat!"

Comment: @J.Doe S.E. comments are a reliable source if they're sourced ;).

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure that it is the "Inory Eye" camera as mentioned in the Planetary Society piece:

> However, the Longjiang-2 transceiver also carried an onboard student-developed camera, dubbed the Inory Eye (a note on the name here) and controlled by a tiny circuit board, which has returned a string amazing images of the Earth and Moon, as well as the lunar surface.

Notice the white balance(WB) differences (assuming these are raw) between [this](http://lilacsat.hit.edu.cn/DSLWP-B/60b486ba-7983-4011-8d9b-f8643d8d36e8.jpeg) image, and the Saudi camera one which seems to have a more balanced WB, and wider FOV. While the tiny lens of the "Inory eye" would result in such types of images that we're discussing.

P.S: Also, the credits are made to HIT Amateur Radio team, and not KACST.